# Dsum function from different records in the same field (sProg_index)

Tags: ms-access

In MS ACCESS
Control Source

```
= DSum("Sites","tbl_data","Fin_Yr='2016' and Qtr='Q1' and sProg_index in ('2.2a','2.2b')")
```

This function is returning a blank value.

In SQL, IN returns values contained in the field (`sProg_index`) with the following '2.2a','2.2b' but I am not sure how to do the same in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid Access SQL and should work. Try it in a query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_data
WHERE Fin_Yr='2016' and Qtr='Q1' and sProg_index in ('2.2a','2.2b')
```

and remove criteria until you get results. Probably some criteria parameter is wrong.

Comment: But what is the equivalent of the same statement using Dsum in the control source.

Comment: I attempted he following but got #Name? error

Dim str As String

str = "SELECT sum(Sites) FROM tbl_data WHERE Fin_Yr='2016_17' and Qtr='Q1' and sProg_index IN ('2.2a','2.2b')"
Me.Text1835.ControlSource = str
Me.Form.Requery

Comment: I meant: create a new Access query with the above SQL. If your DSum expression returns blank, the query should return no records. This isn't what you want, so debug the query by removing / changing criteria. Then apply these changes to your DSum expression.

Comment: Oh I just discovered that Cmd.RunSQL does not return a value, only update, delete or insert.